# how to calculate the average disk_available, based on the hostname hourly , python

Tags: python, grouping, average

result data :

```
<QuerySet [{'disk_available': 26, 'hostname': '2', 'day': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 11, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'c': 354}, {'disk_available': 27, 'hostname': '2', 'day': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 10, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'c': 273}, {'disk_available': 19, 'hostname': '2', 'day': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'c': 12}, {'disk_available': 26, 'hostname': '2', 'day': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'c': 45}, {'disk_available': 26, 'hostname': 'tes', 'day': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 11, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'c': 1945}, {'disk_available': 19, 'hostname': 'tes', 'day': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'c': 53}, {'disk_available': 1, 'hostname': 'tes', 'day': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 11, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'c': 1}, {'disk_available': 26, 'hostname': 'tes', 'day': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'c': 45}, {'disk_available': 27, 'hostname': 'tes', 'day': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 10, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'c': 291}]>
```

Comment: What have you tried and how was it different from the desired output?

Comment: Why didn't you think it'd be relevant to mention this is a django queryset?

Comment: I want to display the average result of hostname hourly, yes it's about django

Comment: for item in x:
    res.setdefault(item['hostname'], []).append(item)

Comment: SocketClient.objects.annotate(day=TruncDay('create')).values('day').annotate(c=Count('id')).values('day',  'disk_available', 'hostname', 'c').order_by('hostname')

Answer (score 0):

```
SocketClient.objects.annotate(day=TruncDay('create')).values('day').annotate(c=Count('id')).values('day', 'disk_available', 'hostname', 'c').order_by('hostname') 

.
```

from the results above I want to do that , I want to display the average result of hostname hourly